# Intuit Reporting services (Balancesheet / profilt and loss)

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

i am using the following code to get the balancesheet and profilt and loss data from quickbooks.

OAuthRequestValidator oauth = new OAuthRequestValidator(accessToken, accessTokenSecret,
consumerKey, consumerSecret);

ServiceContext serviceContext = new ServiceContext(realmId, IntuitServicesType.QBO, oauth);
 serviceContext.IppConfiguration.Message.Request.SerializationFormat = 
Intuit.Ipp.Core.Configuration.SerializationFormat.Json;

ReportService reportService = new ReportService(serviceContext);

```
               reportService.accounting_method = "Accrual";
                reportService.start_date = "2014-01-01";
                reportService.end_date = "2014-06-01";
                Report report = reportService.ExecuteReport("BalanceSheet");
```

it compiles well, but when it runs it gives the following error.

**"
**Ids service endpoint was not found.**

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
Exception Details: Intuit.Ipp.Exception.EndpointNotFoundException: Ids service endpoint was not found.
Source Error: 
Line 133:                    reportService.start_date = "2014-01-01";
Line 134:                    reportService.end_date = "2014-06-01";
Line 135:                    Report report = reportService.ExecuteReport("BalanceSheet");
Line 136:
Line 137:"**

Answer (score 0):

Please use the correct date format YYYY-MM-DD.
Please use response format as JSON as xml is not supported. Your code will work then.
serviceContext.IppConfiguration.Message.Response.SerializationFormat = Intuit.Ipp.Core.Configuration.SerializationFormat.Json;

Comment: nimisha if you see my code block pasted in my question..i am doing what ever you are suggesting

Comment: You are setting request serialization format..not response. Please set this too.